# error 500 when uploading project in laravel 5.7 to shared server

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I am trying to upload a project that I develop in laravel 5.7 to a shared server, but it throws me `error 500`.

Create a folder called `laravel` at the same height as the `public_html` folder, this includes all my files except those found in public. In `public_html` I put all the files in the `public` folder.

Change these lines of my index.php file

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

by

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

In my file `AppServiceProviders` I included in the `register()` this

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function(){
     return base_path() . '/public_html';
});
```

After all this the hosting gives me `error 500`, how can I solve it?

Comment: I remember I manager to get it working by removing `__DIR__` and using absolute path.. say `/home/user/laravel/vendor/autoload.php` and so forth

Comment: @barghouthi brother still the error keeps popping up

Comment: ok.. put app in debug mode.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: in your .env file. APP_DEBUG=true

Comment: That line was already in the file, now what do I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182302/discussion-between-barghouthi-and-edwin-aquino).

Comment: Did you not make a mistake here. The first `require` statement. `require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';`